# Is there a system procedure or method to find out transaction log full issue?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a easy method to find the culprit process holding the transaction log which is causing the pg_wal full isues.

Comment: `pg_wal` can't be full. Only your disk can be full.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction log contains all transactions, and it does not contain a reference to the process that caused an entry to be written. So you cannot infer from WAL what process causes the data modification activity that fills your disk.

You can turn on logging (`log_min_duration_statement = 0`) and find the answer in the log file.

But I think that you are looking at the problem in the wrong way: the problem is not that WAL is generated, but that full WAL segments are not removed soon enough.

That can happen for a variety of reasons:

- WAL archiving has problems or is too slow
- a stale replication slot is blocking WAL removal
- `wal_keep_segments` is too high

Comment: If a transaction is open with no commits for long, a checkpoint won't be able to clear this open transaction, because there is no commmitted data. In that case, the log will keep on filling up and someone would like to know what process is filling up the transaction log? How do we find that out?

Comment: One more thing to add, there are several long running open transactions - how would i know which is NOT letting the checkpoint process to clear the transaction log.

Comment: You are wrong. The changes caused by uncommitted transactions are written to WAL as well, and after a checkpoint these WAL segments will get deleted, even if the transaction is not committed yet. Long running transactions are problematic for many reasons, but they won't bloat your WAL directory.